# Using DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch in case of migrating from Log4j 1.x to 2.x using Log4j 1.x bridge

Tags: log4j, log4j2

According to "Migrating from Log4j 1.x to 2.x" using Log4j 1.x bridge documentation:

> Applications can migrate by just using the bridge without further code
> changes, if they meet the following requirements: They must not
> configure by calling the Log4j 1.x classes DOMConfigurator

My application uses DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch().
I just removed log4j1 jars from my application and added log4j2+Log4j 1.x bridge jars.
And I do not see any issues with logging.
Can someone explain what could be wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `log4j-1.2-api` is not up-to-date and many new features were added in version 2.17.2 (cf. [changelog](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/changes-report.html#a2.17.2)). However not everything is implemented and some methods are no-ops.

In your concrete case [`DOMConfigurator#configureAndWatch(String)`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/8a1bfd56284ff202b6037a65ec4ec5bbb7e9731c/log4j-1.2-api/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.java#L91) does not actually watch for changes in the file, while the version with an additional `long` parameter uses the old `FileWatchdog` that in my experience behaves rather poorly upon shutdown.

A better solution would be to transform your Log4j 1.x XML configuration into a Log4j2 XML configuration and use [`monitorInterval`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax) to request checking the file for updates. Basically "logging through Log4j 1.x, configuration through Log4j2" is a better approach than using the Log4j 1.x "API" for everything.